# List availible NICs on Linux

Tags: linux, mac, networking

I want to list all availible physical (or virtual on DomU) NICs connected to motherboard and see it's MAC addresses.
I guess that related information should be somewhere in /proc or may be in output of some command.
The option to list ifcfg-ethX files clearly not suitable here.

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/sys/class/net/*/address`

Comment: Thank you very much. And here is oneliner for match interface with MAC address. You are welcome to make it shorter: 
ls -d /sys/class/net/* | while read line; do echo -en "`echo $line | cut -d'/' -f 5`\t:"; echo -e "\t`cat $line/address`"; done

Comment: `for i in /sys/class/net/* ; do echo -en "${i##*/}:\t" ; cat "$i"/address ; done`