# How can I find out my computer's hardware details in Linux?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Linux command to find out hardware info?](https://superuser.com/questions/303981/what-is-the-linux-command-to-find-out-hardware-info)

I need a tool for Linux to view my computer's hardware details while I'm logged in.

For example, hardware details like:

- Laptop Serial No
- Processor
- RAM Capacity
- HDD Capacity
- IP Address
- Wireless MAC Address
- Ethernet MAC Address

Answer (score 3):

[What is the Linux command to find out hardware info?](https://superuser.com/questions/303981/what-is-the-linux-command-to-find-out-hardware-info) will give you CPU, RAM and HDD info.

For the networking info you can use `ifconfig`, or for more focussed commands see: [List availible NICs on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/178813/list-availible-nics-on-linux)

To locate the serial number you may find `dmidecode` useful.